# Can't get page_published signal

Tags: django, wagtail

Following the docs found [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/signals.html#page-published) but I'm not receiving the signal. Is there more to add?

community/signals.py

```
from wagtail.core.signals import page_published
from wagtailPages.models import CommunityArticle

from notification.models import Notification

def notify_article_author(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Processing page_published signal")
    ...

page_published.connect(notify_article_author, sender=CommunityArticle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the code is actually being loaded and run - usually this is done by registering the signal [within the `ready` method of your AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready). (If you haven't already, you'll need to define `default_app_config` in `__init__.py`, as detailed at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#for-application-authors .)